# iPhone app localized and internationl

Tags: iphone, app-store

Hi guys I need some help with Apple App Store.
I've an application that is localized in several languages and I want to release a different bundle for each language (to reduce the app size).

Can I use the same app name?

Thx,
SL3

Comment: Don't. People can switch language at any time they want (imagine my best friend from Spain wants to use an app on my iPod touch but couldn't read the Dutch language). Also, for many users: bigger app size = longer download time = **more awesome app**.

Comment: You are absolutely right, but I've to satisfy client's requirements...I completely agree with you.

Comment: try to convince your client of not doing this. Everything will be divided between the apps. User ratings, chart positions, reviews, links to the app, promocodes etc. Nobody sane would want that. Marketing wise this is a very very bad idea.

Comment: Probably the most convincing thing to tell your clients is that it would be cheaper to provide one app bundle, and that it will be in the App Store far more quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Localizing an app in various languages should not require **that much** more size to make you think about splitting it in different bundles.

By the way, it's a bad idea thinking of publishing different applications for different localizations, for a couple of reasons:

1. You will have to handle `n` different development/release/review streams, with great problems when you need to update the app (Apple will have to review `n` versions instead of one)
2. A user will not be able to switch languages if he likes to. Think about a Spanish person that lives in Italy. Which version should he download?
3. If you use dedicate developer profiles under Xcode, you should create and import a different one (or a different group of them) for **each** localized version.
4. Also, you will split all the number of downloads, reviews and so on between the apps. If your app is downloaded by 10.000 people its great! But if you split it in 10 pieces, you will have only 1.000 downloads each (mean value). This will greatly affect the scoring in the App Store ... and that's not what you want!

If you built the app in a clean way, adding a localization should result in adding a simple text file, and that is not so heavy.

Comment: Third reason: updating the app if a minor bug is resolved is a **hell**.

Comment: If you have localized images, sounds or videos the apps grow in size very quickly.

Comment: You could try to avoid localized images. For sounds or video that's the only problem. But you should really consider the disadvantages of multiple, different, app versions

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the same app name or have multiple binaries for the same app version. And as Radek said, it would be a bad idea anyway.